# SendBulkTemplatedEmail, default template data does not exist AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

```
response = ses_client.send_bulk_templated_email(
        Source="admin@example.com",
        Template="NotificationTemplateCurrent",
        Destinations=[{
        'Destination': {
            'ToAddresses': [
                first_email
            ]
        },
        'ReplacementTemplateData' : '{}',
        }
    ],
        DefaultTemplateData = ""
    )
```

I have used other ways to send email with SES before but have not used sendBulkTemplatedEmail. This code gives the error '"An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the SendBulkTemplatedEmail operation: The default template data does not exist", I realise that sendBulkTemplatedEmail allows you to swap in different data for each email but I don't need that for my use case. I am just looking for a way to send bulk emails that are all the same. I have looked into this issue and have seen other people encountering this but have not found a solution, any help with this is appreciated